# Null reference exception for session variable

Tags: asp.net

why am i getting a null reference exception here for Session["Time"] variable upon postback even when i have initialized it in the get request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(Session["Time"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is it your full code?

Comment: Check any of these conditions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996

Comment: This code should not cause an error unless there is a configuration issue. Can you post the stack trace and web.config setting for session management?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be null, I just tested your code and it returns DateTime.Now.ToString().

Perhaps in your global.asax or somewhere in the application you are clearing or not storing session variables.

Comment: setting the Sessionstate mode to InProc under the web.config file solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

it is very possible to be null because you set it only on page load but on the PostBack for any reasons, the session can be null. Can be expired, or the pool recycle and reset it, etc

The page load, from the post back can have a long time distance. Some one load a page, go make a coffee, and come back and press enter... Where is the session ?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  Session["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
// else If is PostBack the `Session["Time"]` can be null !!!
```

Maybe you need to use the `ViewState` and not the session

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(ViewState["Time"].ToString());
    }
```

Or check if the session is not null !